# bringing $-i \frac{d}{dx}$ to the form $U^* M_f U$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

The operator $-i \frac{d}{dx} : H^1(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is self adjoint hence it is unitary equivalent to a multiplication operator

i.e. $-i \frac{d}{dx}= U^* M_f U$ where $U:L^2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, $UH^1(\mathbb{R}^n)\subseteq D(M_f)$ and $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space. $M_f$ is multiplications operator where $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{A}$-$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$-measurable.

What is $U$ and $f$ here?

Using the advice given by "peek-a-boo":

I get for $U f:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i x \overline{y}}f(y)dy$

$U(-i f^\prime(x))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-i x \overline{y}}(-if^{\prime}(y))dy=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}ixe^{-i x \overline{y}}(-if(y))dy=U(f(x))\cdot x$

Thus

$$-if^\prime(x)=U^{-1}M_x U f$$

for all $f\in H^1(\mathbb{R})=H_0^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Yet I just assumed that $g(-\infty)=g(\infty)=0$ for $g\in H_0^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that $e^{-i x\cdot\infty}f(\infty)=e^{i x\cdot\infty}f(-\infty)=0$.
Is this actually true? And why?

As I know Elements from $H_0^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega=[a,b]$ ($a<b$) vanishes on the boundary. This can be justified by the characterization:
[image]

But how is it in generall if $\Omega$ equal the whole space i.e. $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^n$???

Comment: Fourier transform is designed to deal with derivatives. Also, surely you want $n=1$?

Comment: What would be wrong with $n>1$?

Comment: You should need to change $\frac{d}{dx}$ to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}$ no?

Comment: @peek-a-boo thank you very much for youre help so far. It helped me a a lot. I added some further things to the post now.

Comment: Your Fourier transform seems strange. It should be defined (on $L^1 \cap L^2$ functions or Schwartz functions) as in the second or third column of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional) table. Note also property 106.

Comment: @jd27 Thank you. I corrected it.

Comment: I think, youre right there is probably a mistake with the domain.

Comment: Choose your Fourier transform so that it is unitary on $L^2$ (Plancherel's theorem).  Of course $i d/dx$ is an unbounded operator, so your $M_f$ is not defined everywhere, only on a dense subspace.